# Calabash RunLoop::Fifo::NoReaderConfiguredError when trying to launch

Tags: ios, calabash, calabash-ios

I was running Clabash tests yesterday fine, I went home and this morning I am not able to get the app to launch on my physical device (iPhone 6, iOS 9.0.1.) I keep running into the error above, here's the exact output:

```
Error while writing to fifo. RunLoop::Fifo::NoReaderConfiguredError
Failed to launch. Error while writing to fifo. RunLoop::Fifo::NoReaderConfiguredError: Error while writing to fifo. RunLoop::Fifo::NoReaderConfiguredError
```

Then I get a more general error after 5 retries:

```
Unable to start. Make sure you've set APP_BUNDLE_PATH to a build supported by this simulator version
Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher::StartError: Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher::StartError:

"Timed out waiting for UIAutomation run-loop Error while writing to fifo. RunLoop::Fifo::NoReaderConfiguredError.

Logfile: /var/folders/hz/l8c5m9qn31v863pp7lc52b7m0000gn/T/run_loop20151015-2775-4w2qzv/run_loop.out
```

Info on my Calabash setup:

```
calabash-ios version
0.16.4

xcode-select --print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

xcodebuild -version
Xcode 7.0
Build version 7A218

server_version
{
              "device_family" => "iPhone Simulator",
                    "outcome" => "SUCCESS",
                "server_port" => 37265,
           "simulator_device" => "iPhone",
                  "simulator" => "CoreSimulator 179 - Device: iPhone 5s - Runtime: iOS 8.4 (12H141) - DeviceType: iPhone 5s",
                   "app_name" => "Discover",
                "app_version" => "1",
          "screen_dimensions" => {
    "sample" => 1,
    "height" => 1136,
     "width" => 640,
     "scale" => 2
},
                        "git" => {
         "revision" => "3bf68ff",
    "remote_origin" => "git@github.com:calabash/calabash-ios-server.git",
           "branch" => "master"
},
                "device_name" => "iPhone Simulator",
                      "4inch" => true,
                     "app_id" => "com.solstice.discoverfinancialenterprise.mobile",
                "form_factor" => "iphone 4in",
                     "system" => "x86_64",
                    "version" => "0.16.4",
                "iOS_version" => "8.4",
       "short_version_string" => "6.6.1 UAT",
                "ios_version" => "8.4",
"iphone_app_emulated_on_ipad" => false,
           "model_identifier" => "iPhone6,1",
               "app_base_sdk" => "iphonesimulator9.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I went home and this morning I am not able to get the app to launch on my physical device

There is a [Hot Topic](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Hot-Topics) for this exact issue.  The link points to the Hot Topic page rather than the specific issue because the content on that page is ephemeral.

Please update your question with the *exact* command you are using - most important is to include what variables you are setting.